# Убрать анимацию дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Есть код: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwPWGW

Как убрать анимацию у дочернего элемента? При наведении на род. элемент div, анимация срабатывает и на дочерний элемент info.

Нужно чтобы блок info оставался таким как есть, то есть чтобы opacity от род. элемента на него не действовал.

Comment: напишите подробнее, какой эффект у этих двух блоков вы хотите получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал вам положить оба эти блока в контейнер, который будет иметь нужное позиционирование и размеры:

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div id="c"></div>
     <div id="info"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 370px;
}
#c {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #17161D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#c:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 170px;
    background: #0A090B !important;
}
```

А [тут пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwjpGo).